# Javascript, getElementById and style not working: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, css, syntax

I have this code here:

```
document.getElementById('success').style.display("block");
document.getElementById('success').text("aaaa");
```

and I get this error, why?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null 

<span id="success" style="color:#FFF; display:none;"></span>
```

I moved my code to bottom of the page and I get this new error now

`Uncaught TypeError: Property 'display' of object #<CSSStyleDeclaration> is not a function`

Comment: are you running the script after the element is added to the dom? add the code to window load handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
var elSuccess = document.getElementById('success');
elSuccess.style.display = 'block';
elSuccess.innerText = 'aaa';
```

Answer (score 3):

That simply means that at the time of execution of that JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('success')  // is NULL
```

Which either means that there is no element with an id `success` in your document, or it has not loaded so far. Move the Javascript to be called after it has loaded.

Comment: Move my code to the bottom of the page, but now I get a new error `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'display' of object #<CSSStyleDeclaration> is not a function

Comment: Yeah not it means you are trying to style an invalid object. Please post the HTML code of your `success` element definition. BTW, is it a css class that you are trying to style? looks so from the error message

Answer (score 1):

that means

**CASE 1:** your javascript code is getting executed before the element with that id has loaded on that page or

**CASE 2:** no element in your document exists with such an id

if your problem is case 1:

try to place the javascript code just before the closing `</body>` tag

if it's case 2:

try changing the `id` of the element in the lines

```
document.getElementById('success').style.display("block");
document.getElementById('success').text("aaaa");
```

change the `id` `'success'` to some other `id` that actually exists

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('success') != null)
{
 ................................
}
```

Element does not exist with id `success`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using jQuery for this

```
 $("#success").css("display","block");
 $("#success").append("aaa");
```